# Location of generated HTML in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, css, gwt

I want to know where does GWT store the generated html files because when I used firebug I can see div-elements with Id but when I search those in project, I don't find them anywhere.
I see *.cached.html" but I find nothing there.

I need to change some CSS to add scroll effect.

Comment: Firebug is your friend

Comment: Firebug gives element.style but i want to go to html and add a small css on that id.

Comment: If you change it in generated HTML, it won't be everlasting. Try to add style into you GWT java file. If you want to see you generated html files, you can always find it in your webapp directory under the folder name as that of your project same.

Answer (score 3):

GWT does not generate HTML, it generates JavaScript. That JavaScript code is highly likely to create HTML elements *via* the DOM API or `innerHTML`, but that's still JavaScript code, and not “HTML”.

Comment: so there is no way that I can go and access these div elements ?

Comment: You could theoretically modify the scripts, but obfuscation makes very hard. You'd better altervthe elements at runtime with another script, or better, update the source Java code.

Answer (score 0):

```
In firebug console write "document.getElementsById('myDiv');"
```

you can see your div element and click to result and go into your div with HTML view.